# Unity3d Make Player jump/teleport when touching obstacle

Tags: unity-game-engine

in my 2D Game in Unity I have a player that teleports behind an obstacle when touching it. The obstacle is a Rectangle moving from upper screen downwards. So far I made the teleportation effect by just changing the amount of the y-Position. However I had to differentiate a little based on the angle of the player, as he has to "teleport" a bigger distance when he touches the obstacle more with his side. I already implemented this teleportation using the following (quite inefficient) code:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "obstacle")
    {

    ContactPoint2D[] contacts = new ContactPoint2D[10];
    if (collision.GetContacts(contacts) > 0)
    {
        if (rigidbody.transform.position.y < collision.contacts[0].point.y)
            directionOnObstacleTouch = 1;
        else if (rigidbody.transform.position.y > collision.contacts[0].point.y)
            directionOnObstacleTouch = -1;

    }

    teleport()
    }
}


void teleport()
{
    float shift;
    float angle;

shift = 0;
angle = rigidbody.transform.eulerAngles.z;
if (directionOnObstacleTouch == 1) //touching the obstacle from below
{
    if (angle < 90f) { shift = 1.10f + ((90f - angle) / 90f) * 0.25f; }
    if (90f < angle && angle < 180f) { shift = 1.10f + ((angle - 90f) / 90f) * 0.25f; }
    if (180f < angle && angle < 270f) { shift = 1.10f + ((270f - angle) / 90f) * 0.25f; }
    if (270f < angle && angle < 360f) { shift = 1.10f + ((angle - 270f) / 90f) * 0.25f; }
}

if (directionOnObstacleTouch == -1) // touching the obstacle from upper side
{
    if (angle < 90f) { shift = -1.10f + ((angle - 90f) / 90f) * 0.25f; }
    if (90f < angle && angle < 180f) { shift = -1.10f + ((90f - angle) / 90f) * 0.25f; }
    if (180f < angle && angle < 270f) { shift = -1.10f + ((angle - 270f) / 90f) * 0.25f; }
    if (270f < angle && angle < 360f) { shift = -1.10f + ((270f - angle) / 90f) * 0.25f; }
}

Vector2 pos = rigidbody.transform.position;

pos.y = rigidbody.transform.position.y + shift;
rigidbody.transform.position = pos;
}
```

I know this code is not efficient but it gets more complicated when I try to rotate the obstacles. This code works only for obstacles which are plane. Please check the picture attached: how can I adjust the code to make those new teleportations work? Only adding an the width of the obstacle is not working as the player may touch the obstacle from different angles (even with his back).

[what I need to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08nXr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are overthinking it. As I understand for what you said and the images. The player has to teleport in front of the obstacle.

The information that you need is:

- ¿Where is the obstacle looking at?
- ¿Where is the player looking at?

We are going to suppose that the `obstacle.Transform.Right` and the `player.Transform.Right` are where are they looking at.

To check how many if this vector is shared between them you should use a **Dot product.**

One of the things that make Dot product useful is to tell how similar are 2 vectors. If you perform the Dot product of this 2 vectors you can have different outcomes.

- Value of **1**. Means they are facing the exact same direction.
- Value **Positive**. Means they are facing a direction between perpendicular and same direction.
- Value of **0**. They are perpendicular.(Example: player looking up and obstacle right).
- Value **Negative**. Means they are facing a direction between perpendicular and opposite direction.
- Value of **-1**. Means they are facing the exact opposite direction.

So with the value given by the Dot Product you can retrieve how similar is the direction they are facing. And with it you can move the player based on the `obstacle.Transform.Right`.

Here is a link that shows images of the dot product with different values:
https://chortle.ccsu.edu/VectorLessons/vch09/vch09_6.html

An example would be:

```
private float multiplier = 5f;
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "obstacle")
    {

       float dProduct = Vector2.Dot(this.transform.right, collision.gameobject.transform.right);

      if(dProduct >= 0)
      {
         this.transform.position = collision.gameobject.transform.position + collision.gameobject.transform.right * dProduct * multiplier;
      }
      else
      {
         this.transform.position = collision.gameobject.transform.position + collision.gameobject.transform.right * dProduct * multiplier * -1f;
      }
    }
}
```

I don't tested it, but it could be an approach.

Comment: Thank you! I thought the solution would be to go somehow with sine/cosine, but the Dot product seems even simpler (though they actually the same). However... how would an implementation look like? A concrete code seems a little complicated, do you have an idea?

Comment: I edited the answer with a possible implementation. Remember to accept the answer if it is the correct solution.

Comment: I had to extend your code a little as there are different scenarios (obstacle touches you from behind vs. you touch the obstacle from front, both possibilities have the exact same angles), but it works thanks to your idea of using the dot product :) so I marked it as correct

Comment: You are welcome. It may be a bug, but the answer is not marked yet.

Comment: I marked it. As I am quite new it gets not displayed (but still recorded).